# Push notifications API for Appcelerator

Tags: push-notification, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Is there way to send push-nofications in Appcelerator not from console (https://platform.axway.com/)?

For example does Appcelerator have custom API to send push-notifications? e.g. our server sends request to appcelerator API and it sends push-nofication to devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tons of free and open source modules out there with which you can set it up yourself. Some rely on services like [Onesignal](https://github.com/williamrijksen/com.williamrijksen.onesignal), others are completely open.

Keep in mind, for iOS you don't need a module, you just get the token ([as per docs](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Subscribing+to+push+notifications)) and then you just send it to your backend and it works.

A good module for Android with which you can use your own backend is [Ti.Goosh](https://github.com/caffeinalab/ti.goosh/)

Comment: thank you! that's really useful. I've found cloud api in appcelerator where it seems to be possible to send requests from server, but I didn't try it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use axway REST API to send your push notifications.

https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Push_Notifications